# How to centre allign heading of my home page of wordpress site?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, alignment

I have a wordpress site , whose home page is a static page. I want to align the page heading centrally and make the font 48. I went to style.css and changed to :

```
.post-title {
    font-family: Oswald,arial,Georgia, serif;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

As I changed this, heading of all the posts and pages changed to this new setting. How should I change the CSS, so that only the heading of static page will change?

Thanks in advance friends.
(I am not a full time programmer, but I can understand code and do small customization if required.)

EDIT : To clarify, I want to make the changes only on the heading of static page not on all pages and posts. Currently it happens on all pages and posts.

Answer (score 1):

Look deeper into the HTML code, see if the heading is wrapped in a div with another class. To only set the heading you'll probably need to be a bit more specific when targeting it.

```
.header . heading > .post-title {
   font-family: Oswald,arial,Georgia, serif;
   margin: 10px auto;
   font-size: 48px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Ofcoure, if .post-title already has the correct font-family, you won't need to repeat it again for the more specific CSS lines.

```
.post-title {
   font-family: Oswald,arial,Georgia, serif;
   font-size: 16px;
}

.header . heading > .post-title {
   font-family: Oswald,arial,Georgia, serif;
   font-size: 48px;
   text-align:center;
   margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margin for left/right to auto should do the trick:

```
.post-title {
    font-family: Oswald,arial,Georgia, serif;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This changes heading of all the pages and posts, I want to change heading of only one static page which is set as home page.

Answer (score 0):

This will help
put,

```
<div align="center">
// yr code here
</div>
```

this will make sure your content remains center on any resolution.

hope that helps